# How do I get a value from a json dict that's not constant?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write an automation script that needs to get the values from the output below. The problem is the CValue is not a constant number. It can range anywhere from 1 - x sample values. Is there a way I can store each value properly?

```
{
    'Output': {
        'Name': 'Sample',
        'Version': {
            'Errors': [],
            'VersionNumber': 2,
            'AValue': 'Hello',
            'BValue': ['val:val:BVal'],
            'CValue': [{
                'DValue': 'aaaaa-bbbbb-cccc',
                'Name': 'Sample_Name_1'
            }, {
                'DValue': 'aaaaa-bbbbb-ddddd',
                'Name': 'Sample_Name_2'
            }]
        }
    },
    'RequestId': 'eeeee-fffff-gggg'
}
```

Right now, I'm doing it in the most inefficient way by storing each value separately. My code looks like something below:

```
def get_sample_values():
    test_get = command.sdk(xxxx)

    dset_1 = test_get['Output']['Version']['CValue'][0]['DValue']
    dset_2 = test_get['Output']['Version']['CValue'][1]['DValue']

    return dset_1, dset_2
```

It works but it's limited to only 2 sets of the dset. Can you please provide input on how I can do it more efficiently?

Use case is this, I need the DValues for another function that requires it. The format for that request is going to be something like:

```
    Source = {
        'SourceReference': {
            'DataReference': [
                {
                    'EValue': 'string, string, string'
                    'FValue': DValue1
                },
                    'EValue': 'string, string, string'
                    'FValue': DValue2
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: from your example, you have a `list` of `dict`s at key `'CValue'` - what do you want to do with that exactly?

Comment: Updated my post for what to do with the CValue.

Comment: You could extract all the DValues to a list, like `DVals = [d['DValue'] for d in test_get['Output']['Version']['CValue']]`, and work your way on from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) to create a list constructed from the desired element of the `CValue` dicts, then return the list.

```py
return [x['DValue'] for x in test_get['Output']['Version']['CValue']]
```

Comment: the OP already has a list at key 'CValue'

Comment: Yes, I would agree with @MrFuppes  that you can return `test_get['Output']['Version']['CValue'] ` directly without recreating the array.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you?

```py
# either 
def get_sample_values():
    test_get = command.sdk(xxxx)

    return test_get['Output']['Version']['CValue']

# or a generator - maybe not that useful here, but possible
def get_sample_values():
    test_get = command.sdk(xxxx)

    yield from test_get['Output']['Version']['CValue']

# Then you can use it
for value in get_sample_values():
    print(value)
# or 
print(values[3])

# for the generator
values = list(get_sample_values())
print(values[3])
```

For more information https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/